# How to change a value of ListView lable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, listview, label

Hello I'm doing this code in ListView on `ListView1_ItemDataBound` ItemDataBound of ListView
I'm trying this code but not working that is below:

```
int count = 0;
            foreach (ListViewDataItem row in ListView1.Items)
            {
                if (row.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
                {
                    Label Label2 = (Label)row.FindControl("Label2");
                    if (Label2.Text == "") continue;
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        Label2.Text = "Week One Result";
                    }
                    if (count == 2)
                    {
                        Label2.Text = "Week Two Result";
                    }
                    if (count == 3)
                    {
                        Label2.Text = "Week Three Result";
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to change the value of Label based on row count of ListView I trying this code in `ListView1_ItemDataBound` but code is not working I don't where is wrong i did. please help me out with this issue how can i change the value of Label2 in ever row there is a different value of every Label of row 1,2 or 3

How can I do this ? Please help me out .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code. Example of list view itemdatabound.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label2");
        // now what ever u want
        int index = e.Item.DataItemIndex;
        if (index == 0)// here 0 stand for row one
        {
            lbl.Text = "Week One Result";
        }
        if (index == 1)
        {
            lbl.Text = "Week Two Result";
        }
        if (index == 2)
        {
            lbl.Text = "Week Three Result";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will work correctly Raghubar :) . But one thing , Vikram said `value of every Label of row 1,2 or 3` and he use `count`.

Comment: yes zey Raghubar code is working but not giving result i want

Comment: Could you explain what u want?

Comment: Yeah sure i want o to fill Lable based on row like this row 1 label text ="Week One Result"" row two label text "Week Two Result"" ever row have label will have a different number of week